# Windows Service needs to restart after installation of my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, windows-services

I have written a code that sends out Email from Windows Service. Now when my MSI/EXE gets installed, i need to restart windows service once and then the emails get going.

Why this happens?

Let me know if any input required.

Thanks!

Comment: It wasn't started to begin with? Or it was started and then stopped again? Have you tried looking in the event log for exceptions?

Comment: When you install first time, it is stopped. You start the service which is same. <br>Do you means restarting computer?

Comment: Probably better to ask this on www.serverfault.com

Comment: @slugster/@vijay: it is in 'started' mode when installing the application
@monojohnny: it is related to asp.net/C#

Comment: Need more details. How do you send email -- SMTP/MAPI/Exchange web services? Does the call to mail library being made? Does it return successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the service hangs somehow when started from the installer. Does it work correctly if you start it manually after installation instead of starting it from the installer?

If so, in a MSI package you can try using a custom action to start the service after your installation is complete. This action can be scheduled after **InstallFinalize** action in *InstallExecuteSequence* table.